# Updated MacPorts curl implementation behaves differently from previous version and macOS curl

Tags: command-line, macports

I am having an issue with the mac ports implementation of curl.

```
mbp2016:~ pgee$ which curl
/opt/local/bin/curl

mbp2016:~ pgee$ curl --version
curl 7.80.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0) libcurl/7.80.0 OpenSSL/3.0.0 zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.1 (+libidn2/2.3.2)
Release-Date: 2021-11-10
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd

mbp2016:~ pgee$ curl --head https://www.ahpra.gov.au
curl: (35) error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

mbp2016:~ pgee$ /usr/bin/curl --version
curl 7.77.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0) libcurl/7.77.0 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.42.0
Release-Date: 2021-05-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets

mbp2016:~ pgee$ /usr/bin/curl --head https://www.ahpra.gov.au
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 160133
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Set-Cookie: AhpraWeb=1piaikc5vpec3wnhon03ab1b; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
P3P: CP="CAO CURa ADMa PSAa PSDa IVAa IVDa HISa OTPa DELa STP COM NAV INT STA"
Date: Sun, 12 Dec 2021 09:47:21 GMT
Set-Cookie: TS018b815b=0159a15e4f400ce883fd78f837a346d5a62bb71ed32f3cd47fb00b7b3e1515b7af8c96c9498324e287a318da5bbaac588926bd3ce4134eced00319de6fd856439860ec84e7; Path=/
```

So - this shows that the mac-ports installed version (7.80.0) isn't able to connect to a specific server (it can connect with other servers). But the system installed version of curl (7.77.0) does connect to that server.

I did try to force-rebuild curl with :`sudo port upgrade -s -n --force curl` but that had no effect.

This error causes an issue for my development copy of apache/php and in particular the guzzle library. This was working before the update - any ideas how to fix?

Comment: It looks like this is an intentional change in OpenSSL 3.0.0; see [https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16278](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16278). I don't know if `curl` has an option to allow insecure renegotiation. BTW, I know you don't have control over it, but the server setup has other problems; [here's an SSL Labs evaluation](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.ahpra.gov.au).

Comment: i have spent ages trying to get ports to install an earlier version of curl. i could only go back one version - i downloaded the ports tracker, checked out the version and then run the install - but there were no copies on the repositories to build for previous versions - this version had the same issues.  Even using the --insecure option doesn't work.

Comment: OpenSSL (which the MacPorts curl is using) is just being careful to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack due to an outdated SSL server to the server you are trying to connect. You can experiment [with a different *variant* of curl](https://ports.macports.org/port/curl/details/) without openssl. MacPort offers 3 alternatives - darwinssl, gnutl, and wolfssl (`sudo port -v install curl +darwinssl`).

Comment: @sfxedit that works for me! if you make you comment an answer i will mark as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your MacPorts `curl --version` command shows, it uses OpenSSL 3.0.0 to connect to secure http sites, while the macOS `/usr/bin/curl` uses LibreSSL 2.8.3 for the same.

The error you are getting for not being able to connect to ahpra.gov.au is due to them using an SSL server without *Renegotiation Indication Extension*, which makes the secure connection vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack. OpenSSL seems to have chosen to be extra cautious here, and thus refuses to establishes a potentially unsafe secure connection. (The link provided by Gordon Davisson discusses this on Github - [unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled #16278](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16278)).

So if you still want to use MacPorts curl, you will have to use it without OpenSSL. Fortunately, [Macports does offer different **variants** of curl](https://ports.macports.org/port/curl/details/) that do not use OpenSSL. Macports curl is also available with:

- *darwinssl* - Allow secure connections using Apple OS native TLS.
- *gnutls* - Allow secure connections using GNU TLS.
- *wolfssl* - Allow secure connections using wolfSSL (formerly CyaSSL).

You can thus opt for one of these variants. The MacPorts command to install a different variant of an app is

> sudo port install *name-of-app* +*variant*

So in your case, if you want to use the macOS built-in library instead of OpenSSL, you should uninstall the current MacPorts curl (`sudo port uninstall curl`) and install the darwinssl curl variant (`sudo port install curl +darwinssl`).