# UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED on Mac OSX

Tags: python, ssl

I am running some python code that uses a library (urlib3) to access an API for some data. However, when the API endpoint is accessed, I get an SSL error of `UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED`. The library I'm using is utilized by many other users without issue, so I'm pretty sure the problem is with a local configuration on my Mac (or some sort of certificate issue) but I am not proficient with these things.

A google search turns up virtually no instances of this error on OSX. I am using Big Sur 11.6 and the full error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 416, in connect
self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1131)
```

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/432397/237 for an explanation

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks, that's a great find. However, I checked my version of curl and I am *not* using OpenSSL as the person in that link was.

Comment: Your issue is not curl but the version of SSL that is linked into the python libraries